# Old film developed and very bitty... can this be fixed?

Tags: film, image-quality, digital, processing, disposable-cameras

[image]

I found a film from my wedding 12 yrs ago after having a clear out, I got it developed as was desperate to see what was on it as I only lost my husband a month ago... Some photos aren't too bad, ones taken outside, but most taken inside are quite bitty, can this be fixed in any way?
They were developed and sent back on a CD so they are already digital.
Please can someone help?

Comment: What do you mean by "bitty"? Do you mean grainy or noisy? Can you post some samples? Do you only have the CD? That is, no negatives? From your description of outdoor vs indoor results, I would guess that the indoor photos were probably vastly underexposed, and in order to produce any kind of image now, the scanner probably amplified the signal, also amplifying the noisy base - in which case, my assessment would be, there's probably very little you can do to improve them, certainly not without the negatives.

Comment: Yes i do have the negatives... I cant seem to find where i can add a photo to show you. Its not grainy, just has loads of white dots all over it

Comment: @smirnofffff if you edit your post (click the "Edit" link below the tags at the bottom of the post), you can upload an image using the editor tools. see: [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498/175991)

Comment: Thankyou. This is a perticullarly dar one, but then it means you can see the white spots all over it, I have lots more and although i know the pictures werent taken very well as they were disposable cameras, i was just hoping there was some way to make some of them a bit better

Comment: I think its the lighting thats the problem, if they didnt give the flash time to recharge it wont have gone off, other photos are fine and the ones outside are fine too, so i think its deffo the flash, or lack of it :( Sorry for spelling in last post, didnt read it again before i posted it and must have fat typing fingers LOL

Comment: Although i know its the light that was the problem... I'm still desperately looking for any answers that might help me get the best from these photos